# SMART status failing : do I need to replace hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, startup

So, I just 'saved' an iMac A1312 (2009) that was about to be thrown away with a bunch of other computers, at the university where I work. Most of the time the computers that are thrown out are in perfect or almost perfect condition, just a bit old.

So I got that iMac and I am trying to see if it works. Keep in mind I am not used to macOs, so bear with me.

When I first booted up the computer, it sends me into a screen of 'macOS utilities', where I can :

-Restore from time machine

-Install macOS (which is high sierra)

-Get help online

-Disk utility

So I first tried the second option, without success. I get the following error :

'This disk has SMART errors. This disk has a hardware problem that cant be repaired.  Back up data and replace the disk'

Okay, that's not so good. I can try replacing the HDD as last resort, but first I would like to know if there are other possible solutions.

I tried booting from a usb, and formatting the hdd. However, I get the same error if I try to install again. SMART status of the drive is 'failing'.

I'm pretty sure my only option is to replace the drive, but I would like to know if there is something to try first.

(The fact that the computer boots up is independent of the state of the drive ? In other words, am I in the equivalent of the BIOS right now ?)

Edit : I should mention thst I formatted to  'Mac OS Extended (journaled)', with GUID partition scheme.

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac - preferably one that can still run or is currently running High Sierra? You're going to have to swap out that drive, but an 09 can't use Internet Recovery to get you back up afterwards. You need to first establish it can boot to Recovery from a USB stick… otherwise you'll also have to find out if the CD drive still works. Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/85275 too. It's mostly obsolete info now, but has links to installers & resources to make bootable USBs.

Comment: Oops - just realised you said you'd already managed to boot from USB. That gets past one big hurdle. BTW, Recovery is not really a 'BIOS' state, it's a small extra partition on your internal or one can be written to any external drive.

Comment: Are you sure the Mac is a 2009 model? A1312 could also be a 2010 or 2011 model. See [Identify your iMac model](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634).

Comment: It is 2009, I put the serial number Apple's website and the model is iMac (27-inch, Late 2009).

Comment: You might find the [Apple Technician Guide iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)](https://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/imac/imac_27_late09.pdf) useful. If you replace the drive, you will probably at least need to purchase a [In-line Digital Thermal Sensor](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIDIMACHDD09/).

Comment: I am current using a 2011 iMac with macOS High Sierra. The version of the Safari web browser included with High Sierra is to old to work properly with may websites. If you install High Sierra, I would recommend installing a browser which current version works with High Sierra. For example, Microsoft Edge. You might also consider installing a current version of Linux or Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah the temperature sensor thing is a bummer. I was planning on re-selling the thing, but investing in the sensor is a bit annoying, as it costs as much as the HDD itself. Are there HDD that are natively compatible with the cable that is already inside ? For instance, I have seagate drives that have 4 pins next to the sata connector. Or other drives which have two pins. Surely one of these should work ?

Comment: I would assume extra pins are for jumpers and not for connecting additional cables. You would have to download installation instructions from the drive manufacturer to be sure. From the [Apple Technician Guide iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)](https://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/imac/imac_27_late09.pdf), one can determine the 1 TB HDD part number is 661-5174. Searching the web, I found an [used drive](https://www.dvwarehouse.com/661-5174-hard-drive-sata-1tb-3-5-for-imac-27-2009.html) for 48 USD. – 
David Anderson
 6 mins ago

Comment: In the end I did the replacement with a seagate 1 tb HDD that I scavenged. Everything works perfectly, and the fan don't go ballistic meaning plugging in the extra 4-pins was all that I needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set this Mac up to boot from an external drive?

You could then just let the internal one not be used. As long as you have a backup, there’s no need to swap the internal in most cases when it goes to read only mode. Once you are sure you have a backup, I might try wiping it so it’s unformatted and free space so you don’t see it mounted or try copying data to it.

If you want to store data on the drive you need a repair. Either the drive is gone or the cable and controller can’t be trusted to tell a good drive from a bad one. More likely smart is correct and the drive is done being useful. You would need manufacturer tools to determine that for the specific vendor of that HDD.

Comment: FireWire & USB 2… might be a bit tricky, or a bit slow.

Comment: Indeed @Tetsujin but that machine isn’t breaking land speed records for benchmarks a phone runs now on rechargeable batteries.

Comment: I know, but those spinny rust iMacs are still dog slow at 2018 [my folks have one] Stripping it would let the OP put an SSD in, even if it does only run SATA II it would still be night & day. When I first discovered the speed difference it makes, I quickly put SSDs in all the Macs here & kept HDs for longer term storage.

Comment: Yeah, if the only way is to replace the HDD, I could put an SSD in it. Anyway this computer is free, so might as well try it to see what happens, I don't have much to lose !

Comment: @Frotaur this imac is much simpler to open than 2012 and later. In these imacs, the fromt glass is attached with magnets instead of glue, and then its just screws from there. So give it a try! Obviously, make sure to check a video or ifixit guide before starting.

Comment: Is a great machine for DIY repairs. Use it to learn @Frotaur - start with a nice SSD to FireWire or Thunderbolt enclosure (check your ports before buying) and if needed you can then mount it inside later if you need more speed - these macs love internal SSD as it really improves their feel.

Comment: Will do. I have alot of experience with PC's, but not so much with mac's. However I watched a vid and indeed it seems quite simple, I will try it as soon as I get my hand on some suction cups.

Comment: @bmike: Why do you mention Thunderbolt? I do not think 2009 iMacs have Thunderbolt. I have run Windows 10 and OS X on a 2007 iMac and 2011 iMac from the USB 2.0 port. While OK for testing hardware, I would say the performance is to slow for long term use.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson much more likely it’s FW800 - I’ve edited my comment. USB will be painful indeed for anything other than testing or erasing or data recovery